# Error: 'int' is not subscriptable [Python]

Tags: python

I'm writing a text adventure game as an exercise. I'm new to Python. I'm trying to save enemy damage in a dictionary as a range as so:

```
giant_rat = {'name':'Giant Rat', 'Health':15, 'attack':random.randrange(1, 4)}
player = {'health':20, 'weapon':None, 'holding':None}
```

So what I want to do later is access this range and pick a random number
in that range and subtract it from the player's health.

```
atkDmg = giant_rat['attack']
player['health'] -= atkDmg
```

This gives me the error. Shouldn't this work? atkDmg is an integer and so is player['health'] so I'm not sure why it's giving me an error?

Also, if there's a smarter way to implement this then I'm open to suggestions. I want to write the program so that all i have to do is add a new enemy (instead of just putting in the range I want in the battle function loop.)

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks!

EDIT: Okay so here's the actual code. I thought the code above was equivalent to my code but I guess it isn't:

```
# Weapon Stats
weapon = {'Bone':(4, 9), 'None':random.randrange(2, 5)}

# Player Stats
player = {'weapon':'None', 'Health':20, 'Holding':'None'}

# enemy
giant_rat = {'name':'Giant Rat', 'Health':15, 'attack':(1, 4)}
```

And then this is the code that gives me the error:

```
atkDmg = weapon[player['weapon']]
enemy['Health'] -= atkDmg
```

---

```
def battleLoop():

    enemyList = [giant_rat, giant_spider]
    enemy = random.randrange(2)
    stdio.writeln('Suddenly a ' + enemyList[enemy]['name'] + ' appears!')
    attackLoop(enemy)
```

UPDATE 2: I've figured it out, actually. In the code above I forgot to assign a value of enemyList to enemy. I think that should fix my problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your code worked fine on my python shell, 
perhaps you forget to `import random`?

Comment: Edit the full error trace into the question, I don't think we have enough information yet.

Comment: This is a weird issue... I pasted the code in an online ide (for both 2.7 and 3.6) and everything worked perfectly... Check your ide's settings, make sure the code in your ide is the same as what you typed here, and, by the way, you may considering shortening the last part to this:

Comment: player['health'] -= giant_rat['attack']

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with the code you've *shown*, as evidenced below:

```
>>> import random
>>> giant_rat = {'name':'Giant Rat', 'Health':15, 'attack':random.randrange(1, 4)}
>>> player = {'health':20, 'weapon':None, 'holding':None}
>>> atkDmg = giant_rat['attack']
>>> atkDmg
3
>>> player['health'] -= atkDmg
>>> player['health']
17
```

Therefore your problem almost certainly lies in some code you *haven't* shown. Based on the error message you're getting, you have most likely overwritten `player` with an integer of some sort:

```
>>> player = 42
>>> player['health'] -= atkDmg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```